# Bind ALT + Left/Right arrow to HOME and END keys in XKB

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xkb

I have tried a few ways to achieve this but none of them seemed to work, autokey inserts both the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> and end keys in applications. I am looking for a solution in XKB where I have already done a few changes, I want the <kbd>Alt</kbd> behaviour of the <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>arrows to be mapped to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: This question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65434/map-superleftright-to-home-end is exactly what you're asking for. (cc @openas)